# How to flatten iterator that uses references

Tags: rust

I am using the [memmap2](https://docs.rs/memmap2/latest/memmap2/) crate to read some large binary files, and I am using the [midasio](https://docs.rs/midasio/latest/midasio/index.html) library which provides some "viewer" structures that just reference inner structures in the byte slice.

From a slice of bytes (the memory map) I can create a `FileView`, with which I can iterate over `EventView`s, with which I can iterate over `BankView`s. All these just reference to the underlying memory mapped slice.

It usually is trivial to iterate through the `BankViews` in a set of files as:

**Minimal working example:**

Cargo.toml

```ini
[dependencies]
midasio = "0.3"
memmap2 = "0.5"
```

and main.rs

```rust
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::fs::File;
use memmap2::Mmap;
use midasio::read::file::FileView;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<PathBuf> = Vec::new(); // Just the name of some files
    for path in args {
        let file = File::open(path).unwrap();
        let mmap = unsafe { Mmap::map(&file).unwrap() };

        let file_view = FileView::try_from(&mmap[..]).unwrap();
        for event_view in &file_view {
            for _bank_view in &event_view {
                // Here I am just iterating through all the BankViews
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to "flatten" all these into a single iterator such that whenever I call `next()` it has the exact same behavior as the nested loop above. How can I do this?

I need to do it because I want to use the Cursive library and loop through `BankView`s by pressing a "next" button. So I need to control each "next" with a single function that, hopefully, just calls next on the massive iterator.

**I tried**

```rust
use std::path::PathBuf;
use std::fs::File;
use memmap2::Mmap;
use midasio::read::file::FileView;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<PathBuf> = Vec::new();
    let iterator = args
        .iter()
        .map(|path| {
            let file = File::open(path).unwrap();
            let mmap = unsafe { Mmap::map(&file).unwrap() };

            FileView::try_from(&mmap[..]).unwrap()
        })
        .flat_map(|file_view| file_view.into_iter())
        .flat_map(|event_view| event_view.into_iter());
}
```

And this gives me the errors:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `mmap`
  --> src/main.rs:14:13
   |
14 |             FileView::try_from(&mmap[..]).unwrap()
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |             |                   |
   |             |                   `mmap` is borrowed here
   |             returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return reference to function parameter `file_view`
  --> src/main.rs:16:31
   |
16 |         .flat_map(|file_view| file_view.into_iter())
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a reference to data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return reference to function parameter `event_view`
  --> src/main.rs:17:32
   |
17 |         .flat_map(|event_view| event_view.into_iter());
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a reference to data owned by the current function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
error: could not compile `ugly_iteration` due to 3 previous errors
```

Comment: What is the error in your attempt?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks, I forgot to add that info. I have now added it as an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is problematic. Because the `IntoIterator` impls borrow `self` you need to hold both the iterable and the iterator together, and that creates a self-referential struct. See [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct).

It looks to me, even though I haven't digged deep, that this is not necessary and this is actually the result of a wrong design of `midasio`. But you can't do much regarding that, other than patching the library or sending a PR and hoping for it to be accepted soon (if you want to change that, I think it is enough to change the [`&'a FileView<'a>`](https://docs.rs/midasio/0.3.0/src/midasio/read/file.rs.html#496) and [`&'a EventView<'a>`](https://docs.rs/midasio/0.3.0/src/midasio/read/event.rs.html#845) to `&'_ FileView<'a>` and `&'_ EventView<'a>` respectively, though I'm unsure).https://github.com/DJDuque/midasio/pull/8

I don't think there is a good solution. Using iterator adapters is unlikely to work, and creating your own iterator type will require unsafe code or at the very least using a crate like [`ouroboros`](https://docs.rs/ouroboros).

---

**Edit:** With my [PR #8](https://github.com/DJDuque/midasio/pull/8), it still doesn't work verbatim because the `Mmap` is dropped at the end of the `map()` but you still need to access it, however this is fixable pretty easily by collecting all `Mmap`s into a `Vec`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<PathBuf> = Vec::new();
    let mmaps = args
        .iter()
        .map(|path| {
            let file = File::open(path).unwrap();
            unsafe { Mmap::map(&file).unwrap() }
            
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    let iterator = mmaps
        .iter()
        .map(|mmap| FileView::try_from(&mmap[..]).unwrap())
        .flat_map(|file_view| file_view.into_iter())
        .flat_map(|event_view| event_view.into_iter());
}
```

Returning this iterator from a function is still not going to work, unfortunately.

Comment: I am the author of `midasio` so I am definitely interested in fixing any wrong design early before I start using the library more and more. I still am extremely new to Rust; and the fact that I cannot flatten the `EventViews` smelled. All these "Viewers" reference a common outer slice that always out-lives them; I just currently lack the current knowledge to express this properly.

If you have time, could you have a look at the repo: https://github.com/DJDuque/midasio

Any suggestions on how to fix things are welcome. I will start learning more on lifetimes and self-referencing structures.

Comment: @user17004502 I don't have time now, maybe later; but did you try to apply the change I suggested? It basically says "use the original slice's lifetime instead of the one of the viewer instance".

Comment: Yes, I tried your suggestion but I got a bunch of lifetime errors. I *think* this is because my inner slices still are declared with the wrong lifetime. Maybe changing these in the constructor to use "the original slice's life time" will fix things. I am going to keep investigating; you have given me very valuable information. Thanks.

Comment: @user17004502 Sent a PR and updated the answer accodingly.

Comment: Thanks. This is great! I appreciate your help a lot. With respect to using the iterator from the "next" function in a button; I don't think I need to return the iterator, maybe just take a `&mut` and advance it with the button. Cursive also has this `user_data` where I can probably keep the `Mmaps` and the iterator. This is a huge step. Thanks again.